# Antonym for "portioned" or "rationed"?

Tags: antonyms

I'm translating a text about electrocardiography (ECG) into English, and I can't think of an antonym for the word "rationed" or "portioned". For context, the sentence contrasts "rationed" physical activity ("rationed" in this context meaning limited by/through measurement, as in: physical activity where the person's heart rate cannot exceed a certain number), and "unrationed" physical activity, which is a simple 2-minute run. What word would you use in place of "unrationed"? Or can I use it, and it will be understood?

Other options I have come up with through research are unlimited, unrestricted, unmeasured and free. I found the term "free run" in the context of electrocardiography, but not "free physical activity".

(I'm only offering the word "rationed" for explanation and did not actually use it in the translation.)

Comment: Thanks for the information and also for editing in the options you have come up with.  And I hate to be a killjoy, but asking what may be the 'best option' is asking an opinion-based question. (You even use the word 'opinions'.) Trying to formulate an acceptable question on ELU that won't be closed often results in headaches. Are there other articles/sources in English about ECG that you can consult and see what words *they* use, since this is a technical topic? It's my suggestion that you try to find some and go with those. Or, perhaps other folks here will do that work for you.

Comment: What's wrong with any of the options you list in your question? What qualifies them as not as good as what you're looking for? You need to provide something more than *just* a request for synonyms. Is it a certain quality or subtly in meaning that you are after?

Comment: at rest; with 2' exercise

Comment: Thus question is about *portioned* and *rationed*, used as technical terms in a highly specialized field. Only somebody familiar with that field can know what terms are used as antonyms for them in the relevant literature. It is possible that somebody on this site happens to have such expertise, but one is more likely to find such people on sites devoted to the subject matter in question.

Comment: I have no idea of a useful answer but I do know beyond doubt, neither “rationing” nor “portioning” could ever be relevant there; never, not at all. “Rationed" doesn’t in any context mean limited by/through measurement, as in: physical activity where the person's heart rate cannot exceed a certain number. How is ”unrationed" physical activity your simple 2-minute run, please? Your basic choices seem to be to re-define the language or to work more closely within it…

Portioning and rationing are not interchangeable and neither has an antonym; not in this context.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should consider 'unconstrained' here.

[unconstrained](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unconstrained) (MW)

> not held back or constrained

where [constrained](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/constrain) means

> to force by imposed stricture, restriction, or limitation

So in your case,

> a 2-mile unconstrained run

means that there are no limits placed on the patient regarding pace or heart rate during the course of the run.

And conversely, I would use 'constrained' rather than 'rationed' for the other case.

Comment: Cursory googling suggests scientists do use this, but maybe more often in terms of studying freely-chosen paths when able to wander around without restriction, rather than when being monitored on a treadmill.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the antonym of rationed is (as you guessed) **[unrationed](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unrationed)** and the antonym of portioned is (as you could imagine) **[unportioned](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unportioned)**. In this context, none of that works very well since rations and portions are usually physical amounts of something that is being doled out by some authority.

---

Here, you really mean that there are certain guidelines or restrictions that are being contrasted with their absence.

If you phrase the first bit in terms of guidelines that must be met or adhered to, the antonym would be [**free**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/free). Since *[freerunning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freerunning)* can mean a kind of parkour, you might opt for the adverbial form [**freely**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/freely).

If you phrase the first bit in terms of restriction, the antonym would be [**unrestricted**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unrestricted). Cursory googling suggests that plenty of scientists seem to opt for that one. One on the first page of results discusses its subjects’ “unrestricted running at freely chosen velocity.”

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvotes?

Answer (score -2):

The words

> [unlimited](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unlimited)

or

> [unbounded](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unbounded)

describe a lack of limits or constraints on them that 'portioned' and 'rationed' have.